# Java innacurate in calulating my angle?

Tags: java, math, graphics

I am having a user draw a line on the screen, there is a start point and a end point. If the user extends over a certain angle I change the position of the endpoint so the user cannot extend beyond the specified angle. However it seems that when I cacluate the angle the user is drawing and make suer it is not over MAX ANGLE, and set the angle to the MAX ANGLE, there is a difference. This can be seen by when I draw the line, once i get to a certain angle, the line jumps and locks at the MAX ANGLE, but there shouldnt be any jump, it should be smooth, like the line ran into a invisible barrier. This could just be me though, my PosX and PosY are floats.

```
    private void CheckAngle() {
    double adj = Math.abs(PosX - PosX2);
    double c1 = adj;
    double c2 = Math.abs(PosY - PosY2);
    double hyp = Math.hypot(c1, c2);


    double angle = Math.cos((adj/hyp));
    angle = angle * 100;


    if (angle > MAX_ANGLE) {


        double opp = (Math.tan(MAX_ANGLE) * Math.abs(PosX - PosX2));


        if (PosY > PosY2) {
            PosY2 =(float) (PosY - opp);
        } else {
            PosY2 =(float) (PosY + opp);
        }

    }
}
```

My answer was a combination of using radians, as well as unsing

```
    Math.acos() & Math.atan()
```

so the final code looks like this

```
    private void CheckAngle() {
    double adj = Math.abs(PosX - PosX2);
    double opp = Math.abs(PosY - PosY2);
    double hyp = Math.sqrt((adj*adj)+(opp*opp));


    double angle = Math.acos((adj/hyp));
    angle = angle * 100;
    angle = Math.toRadians(angle);

    if (angle > MAX_ANGLE) {


        opp = (Math.atan(MAX_ANGLE) * adj);


        if (PosY > PosY2) {
            PosY2 =(float) (PosY - opp);
        } else {
            PosY2 =(float) (PosY + opp);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Mysticial beat me to it: is `MAX_ANGLE` in degrees? Remember, all the Java trig functions work in radians.

Comment: I am not, not familliar with radians. Ha im taking trig this semester, geez, and people told me i was wasting time taking trig

Comment: To convert degrees to radians, multiply the number of degrees by `pi/180`.

Comment: @JackRadcliffe There's also `Math.toRadians` :)

Comment: if one of you guys posts an actual answer of how to convert say "final double MAX_ANGLE = (80*(pi/180)) I'll accept it.

Comment: Next time, perhaps you shouldn't be so quick to blame Java as being inaccurate. Perhaps instead it's your understanding of Java that was inaccurate.

Comment: Better use [`atan2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29) to determine angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the conversion:

```
final double MAX_ANGLE = Math.toRadians(80);
```

Note that this is identical to saying:

```
final double MAX_ANGLE = 80 * Math.PI / 180;
```

Comment: And of course, there's the `Math.toDegrees` function just in case you need it in degrees again.

Comment: One more quetion, the number that i get from double angle = Math.cos((adj/hyp)); is a decimal like "0.7231" do i neet to multiply this number by 100, then conver it to radians as well?

Comment: Cosine doesn't return an angle.  It's the ratio between the adjacent side and the hypotenuse of a triangle.

Comment: ok looks like what I was looking for was acos(), this is what happens when you wait 3 years between highschool and college, and dont use angles

Comment: Yup, inverse cosine gets you the angle.